# Which one of the following are correct?[CSIR-Dec 2018]

Tags: linear-algebra

[let $M$ be a hermitian matrix of order $n*n$ with rank k$ \neq n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3215590/let-m-be-a-hermitian-matrix-of-order-nn-with-rank-k-neq-n)

My attempt:-

I know that $u^*u=1$. Since eigenvectors are orthonormal set for a Hermitian matrix.
I tried to solve using rank$(M(I-\lambda uu^*))\leq \min\{rank(M),rank(I-\lambda uu^*)\}$ for (1) and (2)
So, option 3 is obviously false. Since, rank$(M(I-\lambda uu^*))\leq \min\{rank(M),rank(I-\lambda uu^*)\}\leq k$
since Rank $M\leq k$
(4) Option is true, since by Induction, I got it is correct. How do I solve (1) and (2)?

Comment: Can you write the eigendecomposition for $M$?

Comment: What do you mean by eigen decomposition?

Comment: Spectral theorem allows one to write a Hermitian matrix $M$ as $M=\sum \lambda_i u_i u_i^*$ where the sum is over non-zero eigenvalues of $M$ and $u_i$ is a unit eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$.

Comment: Why are you posting an answer to an m.se question as an m.se question?

Comment: 1,2,3 will not be true in all situations since they depend on the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $\lambda$

Comment: @Gerry the answer was posted after this question, apparently.  The question remains however as to why he posted another question as a question, though.

Comment: hello, maneesh, please visit the chat, I have pinged you